# Moderator Pro Tem Announcement

Tags: discussion

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Harald Leithner]
[image: Lodder]
[image: FFrewin]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

Thanks also to the past pro tempore moderators [David Fritsch](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/22/david-fritsch) and [Valentin Despa](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/159/valentin-despa).

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: great to see this project grOW!

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for doing this job!

Comment: Good choice. Congratz guys

Comment: Thanks guys for stepping up.   I think you are all great!

Comment: I can't find fault with any of them :) Thanks for volunteering.

Comment: Hopefully with everyone's help JSE will remain a nice place for exchanging knowledge. It will be nice to see the site growing and more people becoming involved.

Comment: Massive thank you to David and Valentin for taking the time to moderate JSE for the last couple of years. Both done an brill job.

Comment: Truly @Lodder - They both offered great service for ~3 years now. Harald remains on the mods team and is a good thing for us the mods newbies.

Comment: @FFrewin - Suppose we best start getting the coffee on :)

Comment: I don't know about you - but certainly you can find a lot of coffee and Joomla in my life ;)  @Lodder - I had a first tour, trying to familiarize with the mods tools & operations... I think we will roll it out -- I guess you can use the mods tools to get in touch with me - but you should feel free to contact me directly - you also have my email address I guess.